# Add dynamical elements in a Iframe element than i create

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic

i have a litle problem if i create a dynamically IFRAME element and i agregate dynamically elements to the new iframe. It works If i do that:

```
var miiframe=document.getElementById("miiframe");
var myElement=content.document.createElement("LABEL");
myElement.innerHTML="blabla";
miiframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

but if i do that doesn't works:

```
var miiframe=content.document.createElement("IFRAME");
miiframe.src="about:blank";
document.body.appendChild(miiframe);
var myElement=content.document.createElement("LABEL");
myElement.innerHTML="blabla";
miiframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

i see the iframe but i don't see the label element.
The most courious is if before appendElement i do and alert it works!!!

```
var miiframe=content.document.createElement("IFRAME");
miiframe.src="about:blank";
document.body.appendChild(miiframe);
var myElement=content.document.createElement("LABEL");
myElement.innerHTML="blabla";
alert("now works!!!");
miiframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

With DIV element works but i want do that with IFRAME element!!!

This code is for Firefox.
Thanks!!

Comment: rather this answer after adding it stop loading it

miiframe.contentWindow.stop();

Answer (score 10):

If you put a "*src*" to your iframe, it tries to load this source (even if it is a "*about:blank*"). After the loading is done, it overwrites your label. You can add a listener to wait for the iframe loading:

```
var miiframe=content.document.createElement("IFRAME");
miiframe.src="about:blank";
miiframe.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
    var myElement=content.document.createElement("LABEL");
    myElement.innerHTML="blabla";
    miiframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(myElement);
}, false);

document.body.appendChild(miiframe);
```

Answer (score 2):

My case was a bit different, I didnt specify any source I was just trying to create an HTML editor, I was making something like this:

```
function init() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttributes('id','edit');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    var y = document.getElementById('edit');
    y.contentDocument.designMode = 'On';
}
```

But that never worked, the curious thing is that when I put some alerts inside some ifs for example if('designMode' in y) and stuff like that, after a couple of alerts I was able to write on the iframe.... :S

Thank you very much for your help, your explanation is clear, the iframe always try to load.... it overwrites any other instruction before... so I changed it and now is working a 100% :)

```
function init() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.addEventListener('load', function () {
    iframe.contentDocument.designMode="on";
    }, false);
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```